# Why does my code does not work even though it is correct?

Tags: c

This is the part of my code. It has 0 errors and 0 warnings but it does not work. It is completely correct. But it does not work.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct details{
    char empName;
    int age;
    float salary;
}det1;

void main(){

    printf("Please enter a name : ");
    scanf("%s",&det1.empName);
    printf("Please enter the age : ");
    scanf("%d",&det1.age);
    printf("Please enter the salary : ");
    scanf("%f",&det1.salary);

    FILE *p;
    p = fopen("employee.txt","w");
    fprintf(p,"%s %d %0.2f",det1.empName,det1.age,det1.salary);
    fclose(p);

}
```

Comment: It is the same reason when a code works though it is not correct.:)

Comment: This statement scanf("%s",&det1.empName); produces undefined behavior.:)

Comment: You really get no warnings from that? Did you tell your compiler to generate them? (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang)

Comment: @Saumya Bhandari Instead of one character  char empName; you should declare a character array.

Comment: I can spot several problems there, any compiler would have given you at least warnings, so I don't believe  your "It has 0 errors and 0 warnings" statement.

Comment: How long are the names you allow? Note that if the program does not work, it is not correct. What warnings you get would depend on your compiler and your chosen options. The code is incorrect in several places (for example, you should never use `%s` when reading into a single character), and dubious in several others. You should check every input, for example. The `main()` function shouldn't return `void`  — though it's semi-legitimate if you're working on Windows. You should check that you successfully open the file before using it. You should include a newline at the end of the print format.

Comment: For starters [this was hinted at by others], change: `char empName;` into (e.g.) `char empName[100];` Then, the `%s` format specifiers will be [more] correct. But, `scanf` has ways to limit the size of `%s`, so you won't overflow (e.g.) `%99s`

Comment: regarding the field: `char empName;`   This is only allocating a single byte for a persons' name.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the OPs posted code:

Running it through a compiler with most useful warnings enabled results in:

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled2.c"  
untitled2.c:9:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
void main(){
^~~~
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:20:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 fprintf(p,"%s %d %0.2f",det1.empName,det1.age,det1.salary);
            ~^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %d
```

so it does not cleanly compile.

Then this statement:

```
scanf("%s",&det1.empName);
```

is trying to insert a unlimited length of characters into a single character.

suggest modifying:

```
struct details{
    char empName;
    int age;
    float salary;
}det1;
```

into:

```
struct details           <-- struct definition
{
    char empName[30];    <-- room for 29 characters + NUL terminating character
    int age;
    float salary;
}

struct details det1;     <-- struct instance
```

then, this statement:

```
scanf("%s",&det1.empName);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
scanf("%29s",det1.empName);
```

Note that '%s' will stop at the first 'white space' so the employee name must be a single word

Note that the '%s' always appends a NUL byte to the input so the MAX CHARACTERS modifier has to be 1 less than the length of the input buffer.

You might try:

```
scanf( "%29[^\n], det1.empName );
```

as that will read input until a '\n' is encountered or 29 characters are read.

Of course, for all calls to `scanf()` the code should be checking the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.

```
if( scanf("%29s",det1.empName) != 1 )
{
    // tell user about problem
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf to read employee name failed\n" );
    // cannot continue so exit program
    // note: 'exit()' and EXIT_FAILURE
    // are exposed via the statement:
    // #include <stdlib.h>
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, scanf for employee name successful
```

because the `scanf()` family of functions returns  the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers' (which for all three calls to `scanf()` in the posted code is expecting a returned value of 1)